# The program created objective c++ is getting crash

Tags: objective-c++

I am developing a application to get list of installed software in Mac OS X 10.5 or above. The program is created using objective-c++ (c,c++, obj-c). Every time I run the program, it is crashing.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])  
{
     NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];    
     //My part of coding
     [pool drain];  // This is the crash prone place
     return 0; 
}
```

Here I'm providing project setting details:

> file extention: .mm
>
> compiled as :   objective c++
>
> Objc GC     :   unsupported
>
> libraries used : libxml2.2.dylib, Foundation Framework
>
> target platfom: x86_x64
>
> development:  Mac OS X 10.6.8, Xcode 3.2.6
>
> Application type: console application

I don't know any other option need to set to compile objective c++. Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

yes. I already set base sdk as 10.5

Here is the log trace:

> The Debugger has exited with status 0. [Session started at 2011-10-03
>   22:29:25 +0530.] GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1515) (Sat
>   Jan 15 08:33:48 UTC 2011) Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation,
>   Inc. GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License,
>   and you are welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under
>   certain conditions. Type "show copying" to see the conditions. There
>   is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys003
>   Loading program into debugger… Program loaded. run [Switching to
>   process 2973] Running… Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
>   sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all (gdb)

I have one more question. Is it valid to release the obj-c object in c++ class destructor?
like this

> myclass::myclasss() {   myobjcinterface* myobjc = [[myobjcinterface
>   alloc] init]; }
>
> myclass::~myclass() {   [myobjc release]; }

Comment: You need to set your base SDK to 10.5.

Comment: Can you post the crash message that you're receiving with the code, it'll make it easier to track back.

Answer (score 1):

> I have one more question. Is it valid to release the obj-c object in c++ class destructor? like this

Yes.

As for your EXC_BAD_ACCESS, if it's hapening on drain of an autorelease pool, it's almost certain that you have autoreleased something *and* released it, so the pool is trying to release a dangling pointer.

Try setting the environment variable `NSZombieEnabled` to `YES` and then running your program.  It should give you diagnostics about over-releases.